# Wicket with JPA and container managed transactions (CMT)

Tags: serialization, jpa, transactions, ejb, wicket

Moving from JSF to Wicket I continue my habits of having all JPA operations in a EJB facade use the container's transaction management. I use and know wicket-cdi for injection, which works fine.

Unfortunately, if I inject an EJB in a wicket page, the serialization checks of wicket complain that it is not serializable. This is true for EJB, I suppose since they are proxied.

My thinking is blocked at this point. How can I use jpa with container managed transactions with wicket? All examples I goggled are just reading data or are using Spring, what I do not want to do.

Thank You
Dieter

Comment: have a look at https://www.42lines.net/2011/11/15/integrating-cdi-into-wicket/

Comment: Thank You, I knew wthis already and I forgot to tell I use wicket-cdi, works fine. The point of my question is mentioned in the second article: "At this point we have the minimum possible integration of Hibernate and CDI. There are a couple of caveats which we will fix in a later post:
No declarative transaction management such as @Transactional or another mechanism.
No way to use EntityManager outside a web-thread because worker threads do not have a conversation"

Answer (score 0):

I repeated the question in the wicket-users mailing list and it was an interesting thread with 3 solutions.

One of them is my idea of encapsulating the EJB in a LoadableDetachableModel and realize the load by a JNDI lookup of the bean. See http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/wicket-users/201210.mbox/%3C5072F013.9040702%40tremel-computer.de%3E

A little more generic solution I posted in [my blog](http://hotchpotch-blog.de/2012/10/09/wrapping-eines-ejb-in-ein-loadabledetachablemodel/), sorry only in german language.